# Python class method type overloading returns invalid type according to Pylint

Tags: python, python-3.x, pylint

I've written a function that returns a `dict` from a config, and am trying to type it so that based on the key, the correct value type is returned (a `list` of an aliased `TypedDict`). I tried to achieve this with method overloading, but am receiving a Pylint error when trying to use the returned `list`: `Value 'x' is unsubscriptable E1136:unsubscriptable-object`. Here's a couple of examples that show the problem:

With these types defined

```py
class AType(TypedDict):
    prop_a: str


class BType(TypedDict):
    prop_b: str


class CType(TypedDict):
    prop_c: str
```

This example using module-level functions returns the type I expect, which is a `list` of the aliased `TypedDict`

```py
__config: dict[str, list[AType] | list[BType] | list[CType]] = {"a": [{"prop_a": "a"}], "b": [{"prop_b": "b"}], "c": [{"prop_c": "c"}]}

@overload
def func(s: Literal["a"]) -> list[AType]: ...
@overload
def func(s: Literal["b"]) -> list[BType]: ...
@overload
def func(s: Literal["c"]) -> list[CType]: ...
def func(s: Literal["a"] | Literal["b"] | Literal["c"]) -> list[AType] | list[BType] | list[CType]:
    return __config[s]


x = func("c")
y = x[0]["prop_c"] # No error
```

However, as soon as I move these functions into a class and try to use the returned value the same way, I get the Pylint error described above (value is unsubscriptable).

```py
class Test:
    __config: dict[str, list[AType] | list[BType] | list[CType]]

    def __init__(self):
        self.__config = {"a": [{"prop_a": "a"}], "b": [{"prop_b": "b"}], "c": [{"prop_c": "c"}]}

    @overload
    def func(self, s: Literal["a"]) -> list[AType]: ...
    @overload
    def func(self, s: Literal["b"]) -> list[BType]: ...
    @overload
    def func(self, s: Literal["c"]) -> list[CType]: ...
    def func(self, s: Literal["a"] | Literal["b"] | Literal["c"]) -> list[AType] | list[BType] | list[CType]:
        return self.__config[s]


test = Test()
x = test.func("c")
y = x[0]["prop_c"] # Value 'x' is unsubscriptable E1136:unsubscriptable-object
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here? For reference, this is with Python 3.11.5 and Pylint 3.0.3, using the bundled typechecker. Also, when I reveal the type of `x` in my editor, it's shown correctly in both scenarios as `list[CType]`.

Comment: [mypy reports no errors.](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.12&gist=05511e45e0796d41e7444d774746d6dc) Could be a Pylint problem.

Comment: @user2357112 didn't think to try with another checker, thanks. I'll report an issue in that project then

Comment: It looks like you might want to use a `TypedDict` for `__config` itself, or is that an artifact of the example?

Comment: @chepner yeah that was just for the example, meant to make that a union of the literals actually. Anyway it turns out there is an active issue for this already tracking for Pylint/astroid, they don't support `@overload` yet